# How to backup PostgreSQL database (a schema) where a user has access to only one schema

Tags: postgresql, backup, schema

I have created a `sales` schema in Postgres.
(so in total there are `sales` and the default `public` schemas)

I added the user `salesuser` to Postgres, and granted it the access to the `sales` schema.

This is how I did that:

```
CREATE ROLE salesuser WITH LOGIN PASSWORD 'password';
GRANT CONNECT ON DATABASE database_name TO salesuser;
GRANT USAGE ON SCHEMA sales TO salesuser;
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON ALL TABLES IN SCHEMA sales TO salesuser;
ALTER ROLE salesuser SET search_path to sales;
```

Now, I'm trying to do a backup of the schema `sales` using the pg_dump and the user `salesuser`.
**The expected result is to backup only the schema `sales`, as it's the only schema the user `salesuser` is allowed access to.**

The command I use is:
`pg_dump -h localhost -p 5432 -U salesuser -d database_name > /tmp/2223.dmp` (note there is no `--schema=` or `-n` parameter)

Unfortunately, somehow the pg_dump tries to dump also the `public` schema, to which the user `salesuser` doesn't have access rights to, as the error below is displayed:

```
pg_dump: [archiver (db)] query failed: ERROR:  permission denied for relation customer
pg_dump: [archiver (db)] query was: LOCK TABLE public.customer IN ACCESS SHARE MODE
```

**I assumed that the pg_dump command with a user** which has only access to a single specific schema, **would backup only this schema**, and other schemas (such as `public`) would be omitted.

I need to avoid defining the `-n` or `--schema=` parameter for the pg_dump.

**I need to focus on access rights of the user with the use case to backup all the schemas the user `salesuser` is allowed to access to.**

How is it possible?
What am I missing?

Answer (score 3):

Looks like usage privilege on public schema has been revoked from salesuser. So, you are getting the permission denied error while dumping the data. [RESTRICTING PUBLIC SCHEMA](https://severalnines.com/database-blog/postgresql-privileges-and-security-locking-down-public-schema)

pg_dump, in general will backup all the schemas(sales and public) of your database.
Hence, you need to explicitly mention -n sales or --schema=schema_name while taking the pg_dump and it will work fine.

You can issue command \dn+ in psql to view the schemas and access permissions.